# Socket close handler and proxy

Tags: python, sockets

im doing some basic socket programming in python. But im having some trouble figuring out how my echoserver could notice that the echoclient has closed it's connection, without a constant ping/pong or timeout.

echoclient.py

```
#echoclient
import sys
import socket
import os
import datetime

def log(s):
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S') + ' - ' + s

s = socket.socket(
    socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 9000))

while 1:
    try:
        foo = raw_input('what do you want to send?: ')
        if len(foo) > 0:
            s.send(foo)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print 'shutting down connection'
        s.close()
        break
    data = s.recv(1024)
    if data:
        print log('Recieved'), repr(data)
```

echoserver.py

```
#echoserver
import sys
import socket
import os
import datetime

def log(s):
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S') + ' - ' + s

port = 9000

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('127.0.0.1', port))
s.listen(5)

while 1:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    conn.settimeout(10)
    print 'Connected by', addr
    while 1:
        try:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if data:
                print log(repr(data))
                conn.send(data)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print 'Closing connection ', addr
            conn.close()
            sys.exit(1)
        except:
            print 'Exception caught! closing connection ', addr
            conn.close()
            break
```

Now the only way the server knows that the client has died is by the conn.settimeout(10)

1. How can i get a exception for my server when the client disconnects preferably without a constat ping/pong message between them or settimeout.
2. My next step is to create a echoproxy between the echoclient and echoserver, will i need to use threads/multiprocessing to achieve this? Any tips or pointers?
3. Anything else you have to comment about bad/good practices is welcome

Thanks!

Comment: using ubuntu 11.10, python 2.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my understanding the socket library already gets a message when [clients disconnect](http://docs.python.org/howto/sockets.html).

> Strictly speaking, you’re supposed to use shutdown on a socket before you close it. The shutdown is an advisory to the socket at the other end. Depending on the argument you pass it, it can mean “I’m not going to send anymore, but I’ll still listen”, or “I’m not listening, good riddance!”. Most socket libraries, however, are so used to programmers neglecting to use this piece of etiquette that normally a close is the same as shutdown(); close(). So in most situations, an explicit shutdown is not needed.
>
> The server can detect “EOF” by a receive of 0 bytes. It can assume it has the complete request. The server sends a reply. If the send completes successfully then, indeed, the client was still receiving.

When the other ends disconnects abruptly (like a network fault or crash) that's when the timeout comes into play.

In your server code above you should be able to immediately detect client disconnects using:

```
if data:
   # process data
else:
   # client disconnected
```

Comment: Not calling `shutdown()` is not neglect. If you have no need to half-close the socket (allow sends by no more receives, or allow receives but no more sends) then just closing the file descriptor is perfectly fine. And that's what most use cases need most of the time. Also, sockets aren't usually part of a library (with exceptions: for example, on Solaris, they used to be). They're usually system calls implemented directly by the kernel. (That's wy you find the docs in section 2 of the manual.)

Answer (score 0):

The Python socket library is a low-level implementation, so it can be tricky to use.  I would recommend using something higher level, such as Twisted.  You can do exactly what you're looking for in Twisted with the connectLost method.

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol

class Echo(Protocol):
    def connectLost(self, reason):
        pass
```

See http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/servers.html for more info.

(Twisted also might make the proxy easier to implement as well.)

Comment: i guess there is something similar with gevent which i plan to use in the future. I do this as small exercises to create a irc proxy in the following months as my first python socket application. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't look like you can do what you're looking for with plain sockets without a "ping/pong" or "heartbeat." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697989/socket-lose-connection

Answer (score 0):

Use `socket.shutdown()` before calling `socket.close()`. Read the note give for `socket.close()` [here](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket-objects)